# Android toolbar heigth is small in API 23 and upper version

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My problem is in toolbar heigth. So, I tested the application on API 19 device and toolbar height was OK but in API 23 and upper version toolbar height is small. I used CollapsingToolbarLayout. I could not find any solution for this problem. The problem raise when I change the visibility of Relative Layout to 'GONE'.So when the Relative Layout is visible and when I collapse the toolbar, it turns like in API 19 and works fine. But when I change the visibility of the layout to 'GONE', the problem rise. [android API 19 toolbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSdlO.jpg)       [android marshmallow toolbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXDo7.png)

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context="androlite.androidfragmentsearchview.MainActivity">



            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapse_commonview_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">

                <RelativeLayout

                    android:id="@+id/hs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/header"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/pecat"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/opacityFilter"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="#F1103AA2"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


                <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

Comment: Try this - Use a NoActionBar style in the app styles.xml and set your toolbar as supportActionBar.

Comment: probably setsupportActionBar() fix your problema.

Comment: I changed popupTheme to   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"  but it does not help